# New to Linux - Blank screen after attempting to update lubuntu

Tags: updates, lubuntu, startup

I am relatively new to the whole Linux world, so I might be missing something, but I tried to update lubuntu on my “Lenovo IdeaPad 100 S-14IBR”. Basically, the update appeared to download (run through a terminal, but apologies I do not remember what the command was) and prompted me to restart my laptop. I restarted the laptop, now all I get is an illuminated blank screen. It’s definitely not the monitor. I unplugged the main battery and unplugged the “clock” battery (assuming I cleared the ROM). When I did that and turned it back on the upper left said: “System is reconfiguring... will reset soon” (or something to that effect). Then it looks to reset quickly then goes back to an illuminated blank screen. If I power the device off then on without unplugging the batteries, no text appears on the screen, it lights up (blank screen) but nothing happens. I am using this device and a good way to learn about Linux and troubleshoot problems I encounter. Any advice in all areas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try pressing Alt+Ctrl+F1 keys together. Do you see a command prompt?

Comment: I appreciate your response. I did try Alt+Ctrl+F1. Unfortunately no command prompt came up on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: I actually found out that my Lenovo laptop has a NOVO button to enter the BIOS. I took apart most of the laptop when discovering this. I was playing around with the motherboard so the battery and clock battery was unplugged. I solved this issue by disabling secure boot in BIOS security tab. Lubuntu started right up.